# How to sync Time with NTP server on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, registry, ntp

I'm trying to find a way to sync my machine (win 7/8.1/TH) time with an NTP server every **x** time.
i.e sync clock every 1 hour.

I understood there's a way to do it by configuring something in the registry.

Another good solution can be a way to automatically run a **.bat** file every **x** time, which will contain

> w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:" + NTPServerAddress

But I prefer a reg solution if possible.
THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution here [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2008/02/26/configuring-the-time-service-ntpserver-and-specialpollinterval.aspx)

Basically you just need to go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\ 
NtpClient\SpecialPollInterval** and change the value to whatever you want the interval to be.

its important to start the w32Time service before (from cmd) with:

> net start W32Time