# Use a time command in a batch file

Tags: time, cmd

In my job there is a time problemes in all the computers.
There is 17 minutes less than "normal time" but i can't fix it by graphic interface so i do cmd : time
But it done it 10-11 times in the day, it's a little bit boring.
Does it exist a batch command to add 17 minutes at each click on the batch.exe ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32179446/2152082) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22862236/2152082) might be helpful. If not, also take a look to the "related" list there.

Comment: Finding the reason that the time is so far off might be worthwhile. Also, Windows already has a way to sync with a time server.

Comment: Open a command prompt window , run `w32tm /?` and read the output help. Windows computers not being part of a domain synchronize their time by default with an NTP server of Microsoft. Windows computers being part of a domain synchronize their time with the domain controller. You should really find out why synchronization with the time source (NTP server or domain controller) is not done respectively why time source has a wrong time. It is of course possible to use a different NTP server than the one by Microsoft and change the parameters for NTP synchronization.

Comment: I suggest to open __Services__ and check if __Windows Time Service__ is set for being started automatic and is running as otherwise no synchronization with NTP server / domain controller is processed from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to auto sync to a time server.

Comment: No it's the serv who is  the problem BUT i don't have  access to it

Comment: You can make a sheduled task in windows launched every day for example at 12 o'clock that execute time command and set time to 12:17

Comment: After 1 hour difference you won't be able to login to a server.

Comment: OOh so i  will  avoid  doing that so ^^